# vs-code is muffing up my indentation in powershell for some reason

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Switched to vs-code from vim for editing powershell scripts.  Bit of a learning curve, but it's working.  However, there is one indentation problem I cannot figure out.  It's not a dealbreaker, but it's annoying.

So for the sake of argument, a long function call, with long strings for parameters, multiple parameters, etc.  On one line, it's ridiculously long.

So I split the line with the backtick `, and that's OK.

The problem comes when I start the next block of code, be it another call to the function, or some other power-shell statement, vs-code indents it to the same depth as the last parameter.  I don't have () or any of those characters, and I have to shift-tab a zillion times to get the new line of code back over where I want it.   How do I get the editor to understand that it's really a new line/back to the old indentation level?  If I put a # character in the first column then everything is back to OK.

Typing it in would lose the formatting issue and defeat the purpose, so I'm pasting in a pic.  The code itself is trivial, the first Get-Item is in the wrong spot, the 3rd "SomeFunctionInSomeModule..." call is lined up wrong.

[image: pic of issue in vscode]

Comment: you should NOT have any backtick after the last parameter. ///// however, a better solution is to use "splatting". this ... `Get-Help about_splat*`.

Comment: There aren't any backticks.  At least in my theme, backticks are the white.  After the string "Last Parameter", it's a single quote for the end delimiter of the string.  However, I will check out splatting, that might be handier.

Comment: EVERY  `-Param2` on your image has a backtick after it.